# Замена в цикле текста в дивах на значения в массиве

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Доброго времени суток.У меня такая задача. Имеется массив: `var arr1=["a","b","c","d"];`
Иммеются 4 дива, мне нужно в цикле поменять значения текста в этих дивах

```
$('.selectionOrder .leftCol').find('.text').text(function(index){
          как написать замену ???
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.selectionOrder .leftCol').each(function(index){
          $(this).find('.text').text(arr1[index]);
});
```

подробнее: [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)